# Objects render with grey lines Cycles, Blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Good day

Some of my objects seem to render with strange grey lines and shapes. Using cycles in blender 2.8.

Here is my render.
[image]

does anyone have an idea of what might be causing this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Hello :). Perhaps you have a duplicate mesh hidden in viewport, but allowed in render.

Comment: If you're using a solidify modifier it could be a too low thickness value.

Comment: @JachymMichal. You were right. I realized I had duplicate objects on top of each other. Thanks to both of you